# Slice column of arrays to the minimum size

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame with 2 columns that contain a list of ids. I would like to slice the ids to the minimum size.

```
          id_l       id_r                  id_l       id_r     
-------------------------        -------------------------
       [20,16]       [86]     >            [20]       [86]
          [18]   [12,642]     >            [18]       [12]
          [22]       [58]     >            [22]       [58]
      [1,2,26]     [5,60]     >           [1,2]     [5,60]
    [25,12,50] [13, 3,35]     >      [25,12,50] [13, 3,35]
           ...        ...                   ...        ...
```

For example, `min( len([20,16]), len([86]) )` is `1` which is the possible max size of the list. 
Hence, the first list needs to be sliced to accommodate that, resulting in `[20], [86]`

My current solution is this:

```
df.loc[:, "id_l"] = df.apply(lambda x: x['id_l'][:min(len(x['id_l']), len(x['id_r']))], axis=1)
df.loc[:, "id_r"] = df.apply(lambda x: x['id_r'][:min(len(x['id_l']), len(x['id_r']))], axis=1)
```

I have also attempted break it down by creating a new column that contains the mimumum size and using that to slice it.

```
df.loc[:, "l_size"] = [len(x) for x in df["id_l"]]
df.loc[:, "r_size"] = [len(x) for x in df["id_r"]]
df.loc[:, "min_size"] = df[["l_size", "r_size"]].min(axis=1)

df.loc[:, "id_l"] = df.apply(lambda x: x['id_l'][:x['min_size']], axis=1)
df.loc[:, "id_r"] = df.apply(lambda x: x['id_r'][:x['min_size']], axis=1)
```

However, this approach is really slow, mostly the `df.apply` function. I was wondering if there is a better way to do this. Possibly a vectorized approach.

Comment: Honestly, no not really. `pandas` is not meant to store objects. You need to change each of those objects so there will be a heavy penalty. You might be able to hide the loops with something like `expode` + `groupby` to get values, but again those are going to be faily slow and you're going to pay a very heavy price when you ultimately `.agg(list)` in the end. Really if efficiency is an issue you should rethink how you're storing the lists. If you can start and store things in a `MultiIndex` and work in that framework then this can be done very quickly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If efficiency is a concern then you need to ditch the lists and switch to a `MultiIndex`. The outer level is your row-index, the inner level would correspond to the list index. I advise you try to get to this organization **before** you have the lists in your DataFrame, else you need to use `explode`, which isn't the fastest.

#### Sample data

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id_l': [[20, 16],[18], [22], [1, 2, 26]],
                   'id_r': [[86], [12, 642], [58], [5, 60]]})
```

#### Code

```
def explode_with_cumcount(s):
    s = s.explode()
    s.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([s.index, s.groupby(level=0).cumcount()])
    return s

df = pd.concat([explode_with_cumcount(df.id_l), explode_with_cumcount(df.id_r)],
               axis=1, keys=['id_l', 'id_r'])

#    id_l id_r
#0 0   20   86
#  1   16  NaN
#1 0   18   12
#  1  NaN  642
#2 0   22   58
#3 0    1    5
#  1    2   60
#  2   26  NaN
```

---

Now without lists it's very fast and efficient to truncate to the smallest size.

```
df = df.dropna(how='any')
#    id_l id_r
#0 0   20   86
#1 0   18   12
#2 0   22   58
#3 0    1    5
#  1    2   60
```

If you require the lists, the `.agg` will be on the slow side

```
df.dropna(how='any').groupby(level=0).agg(list)
#     id_l     id_r
#0    [20]     [86]
#1    [18]     [12]
#2    [22]     [58]
#3  [1, 2]  [5, 60]
```

Comment: The way I am ending up with a list of ids is by aggregating the ids of the grouped rows. How can I end up with `MultiIndex` that way?

Comment: @AzimjonIlkhomov in that case use what I did with `s.groupby(level=0).cumcount()`. `groupby ` + `cumcount` enumerates rows within each group (in your case `ID`) then you can add that newly created column as the index level.

Comment: I just realize I spent time to pretty much do the same thing, so I'll just +1 this.  As an aside, would this be more efficient than just an `apply`?

Comment: @r.ook If the lists are necessary, I would be surprised if it were greatly more efficient than an `apply`. `explode` is slow-ish but not bad. Certainly if you could start from the MultiIndex, subsetting with `df.dropna(how='any')` is going to be far better than any apply to modify the data. However the issue is that then I need to `.groupby(level=0).agg(list)` and that is just a hidden loop over the rows because AFAIK `.agg(list)` isn't some cython optimized method so you pay the price there.

Comment: The main take away should be that if you require lists, then you can do all the gymnastics you want, but you won't save yourself much. On the other hand, rethinking the organization such that you store scalar values is a far better use of time, though I realize it can often seem like the much more difficult problem to solve, and sometimes external APIs/requirements don't allow that :(